# Consuming web service using asp.net and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am trying to use/consume a web service in Visual Studio 2010. Documentation of API has provided 3 urls:

- http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/services/webpayservice.svc
- http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.xml
- http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.json

Documentation gives two examples. For json they says sample request to be like:

```
Http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.json?productid=21&transactionreference=8421941122&amount=300000 HTTP/1.1
UserAgent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.239)
Hash: F6FF2E22F99D93DDDA52D71811FD92B3A71FA1968A66216E0D310DAD
```

and for XML:

```
GET Http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.xml?productid=21&transactionreference=8421941122&amount=300000 HTTP/1.1
UserAgent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.239)
Hash: F6FF2E22F99D93DDDA52D71811FD92B3A71FA1968A66216E0D310DAD
```

Documentation doesn't give example of consuming the `.svc` url

I am trying to use `Add -> Webservice Reference` in VS 2010 but I keep getting the following error for the `.svc` url (first one in above 3):

> *There was an error downloading `https://testwebpay/test\_paydirect/services/WebPAYService.svc?wsdl`.
>
>   The remote name could not be resolved: 'testwebpay'
>
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: `https://testwebpay/test\_paydirect/services/WebPAYService.svc?wsdl`.
>
>   There was no endpoint listening at `https://testwebpay/test\_paydirect/services/WebPAYService.svc?wsdl` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
>   The remote name could not be resolved: 'testwebpay'*

Which of the above 3 URLs do I need to use to add service refernce. Is it problem on service end or am I doing something wrong ?

Please suggest

Comment: @marc_s I am using full url like this http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/services/webpayservice.svc

Comment: you mean interswitching.com instead of interswitchng.com ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather odd web service....

If you go to URL you provided as the first URL:

```
http://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/services/WebPAYService.svc
```

you get a "help page" that shows you - yes, indeed, there's a SOAP service living here.

**BUT:** the URL for adding the web reference at the top of that page is **invalid**:

```
https://testwebpay/test_paydirect/services/WebPAYService.svc?wsdl
```

It's a *local* web address - missing the domain name .....

So based on this URL, you really must connect to

```
https://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/services/WebPAYService.svc?wsdl
```

in order to get the SOAP definition for the service (the Web Service Description Language file that describes all the details of this service). Once you connect there, and once you ignore the certificate problems (if you trust that company / service provider), then you get the proper WSDL and you can build your service client.

Alternatively: go to

```
https://testwebpay.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/services/webpayservice.svc
```

(your first URL, but with `https://` instead of `http://`) and you get the proper URL for the WSDL right from the beginning...